# Correct JSON REST Controller by Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

I am new in writing spring rest controller. I want to create a simple sending in JSON format, but I can't deal with it, is my code a correct code for it?

In my code, there is a RestTemplate, which sends a simple POJO to the REST url, and the REST Controller sends back another POJO.

I found a lot of examples sending and receiving objects as JSON, but some of them are a few years old. The most I found is where they configure the dispatcher bean XML by adding `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for *Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa*:

```
...
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean> 
...
```

And also they set it to the RestTemplate java code:

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

Sometimes they set a header too:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
HttpEntity<MyObject> entity = new HttpEntity<MyObject>(inputRequest, headers);
```

Sometimes they convert their object to JSON format, and send it as a text, not the instance.

And also I can found 2 ways for sending a POST message:

```
ResponseEntity<MyObject> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, MyObject.class);
```

or

```
MyObject response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, inputRequest, MyObject.class);
```

And this is the REST Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public MyObject send(@RequestBody MyObject requestModel) {
    return //whatever;
}
```

BUT: if I don't set anything into the XML, and don't add any message converter and header to the RestTemplate, it looks like it working fine. I test it by PostMan, and if I add a JSON format of my MyClass example, I receive JSON.

***So my question is: Is my code correct this way for JSON sending really?:***

**mvc-dispatcher.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <!-- to reach resources like css and images -->
    <default-servlet-handler/>
    <!-- the REST controllers are here -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="hu.viktor" />
</beans:beans>
```

**RestTemplate java:**

```
@Controller
public class RequestSender {
    public MyObject send(MyObject inputRequest) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/rest/send";
        MyObject response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, inputRequest, MyObject.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**And the REST Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class CalculatorRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public MyObject send(@RequestBody MyObject requestModel) {
        return //whatever;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-enable) `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` will be added automatically, if you specified `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in xml configuration (in your case just `<annotation-driven>`). The same documentation contains the list of  `HttpMessageConverters`, which will be set up by `<mvc:annotation-driven>'`. And:

> `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` converts to/from JSON — added if
>   Jackson 2 is present on the classpath.

This means, that you don't need to add json message converter manually, just specify `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in configuration file and declare dependencies in your pom.xml (if you're using Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yes, these dependencies already added to my pom.xml. so my final code is right? no need to add anything to the xml and to the RestTemplate?